# For loop with custom order

Tags: forloop

So I'm trying to loop through some entries and order them by in a specific way. For an example let's say I have the following entires:

- Example01
- Example02
- Example03
- Example04

I now want to loop through these entries and order them in an order such as: Example03, Example01, Example04 and Example2. The order has to be custom where I can change it.

Is this possible and if so how can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here:

- Use an Entries field (as a Global or as a fields on a Single maybe?) to chose the entries and order them
- Make the Entries a Structure section, so you can set the order
- use `craft.entries({ ids: [3, 1, 2], fixedOrder: true })` and query the Entries by ID (if they'll never be deleted and you're cool with hard-coding the order)
- create an `order` field on that entry type to query them by, also with `craft.entries()`

It's up to you what the best solution would be, given your set-up, but you have plenty of options.

Comment: Is there a means of hard-coding order in templates using slug rather than ID? At the moment I have multiple for loops with if conditions, each matching a slug.